# Command Line Tips and Tricks

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

==>> **What are the most useful Unix shell "one-liners" that you use?** <<==

Here are a couple of mine to get the conversation started:

### 1. Repeat the previous command with a substring replacement:

*Syntax*:

```
^before^after^
```

*Example*:

You entered:

```
git clonr https://unbelievablylongurl.org/projectdirectory/evenmoreprojects/project.git
```

Use this:

```
^clonr^clone^
```

And your command will be re-run with the replaced substring:

```
git clone http://unbelievablylongurl.org/projectdirectory/evenmoreprojects/project.git
```

### 2. Repeat the previous command with an additional string/character

*Shell Idiom*:

```
!!
```

*Example*:

You ran a command that requires superuser privileges on your box.  Re-run the command without retyping it like this:

```
sudo !!
```

Comment: You're about four years late to this... Welcome to the site. I would encourage you to ask about 10 very specific questions with a problem you are trying to solve before attempting a "survey question". The community is peculiar about which they embrace and which they extinguish with great rapidity even where there isn't a duplicate.

Comment: I have unprotected the linked question so you can add your examples here as answers if they aren't already covered.

Comment: Excellent, thank much for your responses.  My apologies for the duplication of the previous question.  I read through the responses to the question there and it seemed that there were a combination of shell scripts, functions, variables, bash settings, etc.  I was hoping to have a bit more targeted conversation about useful, elegant single line shell commands.  Will add these to that thread. Best, -C

Comment: If there's a different problem, go ahead and edit this to make it clear what problem is being solved here (as opposed to a "greatest hits") and we can look at reopening it. No worries - closing is just a temporary chance to edit and reopen if there is a better way to phrase this.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I appreciate your help.  Will gain some street cred and then may try to broach this topic again.